# Как получить список односложных слов русского языка?

Tags: поиск-api

Нужна штука для поиска слов. В данный момент интересуют 2 параметра поиска: количество слогов и часть речи.

Мне казалось что должен быть какой-то сервис или апи, но за почти час гуглинга ничего подходящего не нашел.

Если вы тоже не знаете готового решения, поскажите на базе каких технологий(библиотек, пакетов..) и данных вы бы реализовали решение (простота реализации -- ключевой фактор), так чтоб его потом можно было "докручивать" по мере необходимости.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У `wiktionary` есть [открытый API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page).

#### Как искать слова

```py
import requests

word_to_find = "язык"

session = requests.Session()
base_url = "https://ru.wiktionary.org/w/api.php"
params = {
    "action":"query",
    "format":"json",
    "titles": word_to_find # здесь слово, которое ищем
}

response = session.get(url=base_url, params=params)

print(response.json()["query"]["pages"])
for k, v in response.json()["query"]["pages"].items():
    if k != "-1":
        pageId = v["pageid"]
    else:
        print("Нет такого слова в этом словаре")
        pageId = None
```

#### Количество слогов == количеству гласных в слове

```py
vowels = "ауоыиэяюёе"
count_syllable = len([letter for letter in word_to_find if letter in vowels])
```

Для остального же существует действие `parse` у данного API, которое позволяет забрать страничку с известным `pageid`

```py
params1 = {
    "action":"parse",
    "format":"json",
    "pageid": pageId 
}

response1 = session.get(url=base_url, params=params1)
```

А дальше разбирать ответ через какой нибудь `beautiful soup` и искать часть речи. Я таким не занимаюсь, поэтому не силен.

#### Другой подход

Можно забрать уже готовый список русских слов и поработать с ним, например [здесь](https://github.com/danakt/russian-words).

[Библиотека для морфологичесокго анализа](https://pymorphy2.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

Ну, и напоследок [морфологический словарь](http://opencorpora.org/dict.php)

Comment: Лучшего ответа не мог бы и представить, поклон нижайший @Dmitry

Comment: @FakeFish нет проблем, на здоровье